# Is there a way to filter the typeahead.js selections right before opening the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

typeahead.js has the `prefetch` options to get the datums before they are needed.

```
$('input').typeahead({
    "prefetch": "/selections_url"
});
```

What I would like is to filter the selection based on some information in the document. `prefetch` can also filter the initial datums when using the `filter` option. But this only filters the initial fetch. What I need is indeed `prefetch` but with a hook to filter out some datum just before they are displayed.

typeahead.js has this event `typeahead:opened` but this has no arguments (cannot process datums) and is triggered before the datums are rendered in the dropdown (so I cannot write a piece of code to remove some rendered datums)

Any way to do this?

PS: I have also added this [issue](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/424) in the typeahead.js project.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could use `remote` (making an AJAX call) and pass your document data to the server side, and have the server side populate.

A hack is immediately implied:

1. Use `prefetch`, and in its `filter` store a reference to the data. Have the `filter()` itself return an empty set.
2. Have an empty remote URL (or a URL that points to an endpoint that does nothing), and in *its* `filter`, read the data that you stored in `prefetch`'s `filter`, do whatever you want with your document data, and return any subset of that.